# Oracle change connection identifier

Tags: oracle

I have 2 Oracle database installed on 2 different server (production and test) but I'm not Oracle expert. In production I can connect succesfully via SQLPLUS using:

```
sqlplus user/password@bc.name.server.com
```

In test system I have to specify different connection string:

```
sqlplus user/password@bc.name.server.com:1521/orcl
```

Whithout the `:1521/orcl` I got:    `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

For scripting purpose, I would like to use the same connection string but I'm stuck on how to change it.
I tried to change the tnsnames.ora as:

```
ORCLCDB=localhost:1521/orclcdb
bc.name.server.com=
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

But still not work. Could someone address me on how I can change the connection string to:

```
sqlplus user/password@bc.name.server.com
```

Thank you
Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do that; see if it helps.

As every Oracle piece of software uses its own `TNSNAMES.ORA` file (for example, if you installed Oracle database and Developer Suite, you'd have two `TNSNAMES.ORA` files). In order to be able to connect to different databases, you have to maintain `TNSNAMES.ORA` in both (or more) directories. To avoid that, create `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable which points to a directory that contains a single copy of the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file. Therefore, when I add a new database to connect to, I maintain it only in that `TNSNAMES.ORA` file. On my computer, it is set to

```
SQL> $set tns_admin
TNS_ADMIN=C:\oralib
```

Contents of my **SQLNET.ORA** file:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Contents of my **TNSNAMES.ORA** (part of it, though; in reality, I currently have aliases to 56 databases in there):

```
MY_TEST_DB=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=my_test_host)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SID=db_test)
    )
  )
  
MY_PRODUCTION_DB=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=
        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=my_production_host)
        (PORT=1521)
      )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SID=db_production)
    )
  )
```

When I'm connecting to these databases, I run (at the operating system command prompt)

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@my_production_db

or

sqlplus scott/tiger@my_test_db
```

and everything works just fine.

Comment: Should be noted that Oracle alias resolution can be also done by other methods, e.g. Oracle nameserver (OID). See https://datacadamia.com/db/oracle/naming_method For 50+ databases, the OID might be an option.

Comment: Thank you, @Wernfried. Hopefully, in a matter of months, approx. 40 databases will be shut down which will make things simpler.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems it doesn't work for me. I edited the following file: /u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora and added exactly as per your example (with my data). I reboot the server just to be sure, ma still got the same error as op. It seems oracle totally ignore the tnsnames.ora file. For your information I'm on RHEL 7

Comment: EDIT: it works for system user, but NOT for user I created. What could be the problem?

Comment: It should work for any user, as far as I can tell.